# SQL select from three Tables and save in PHP array

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a web application and would like to improve my code a little bit.

This is the SQL table structure I made for the application:

[image]

Now my question: Is there an easy way in PHP to select (with join or whatever?) the information from one specific event_id on all tables and save them in an array with followed structure for example:

```
$events = array(
    'event_id' => 1,
    'event_name' => '{"de":"Weltwirtschaftsforum","fr":"Forum \u00e9conomique mondial","it":"Forum Economico Mondiale"}',
    'event_description' => '{"de":"Description DE","fr":"Description FR","it":"Description IT"}',
    'event_lastedit' => 2011-12-01 10:23:35,
    'locations' => array(
        array(
            'location_id' => 1,
            'location_name' => 'Bern',
            'location_date' => '01.01.2012',
            'location_deadline' => 1323340607,
            'timestamps' => array(
                array(
                    'timestamp_id' => 1,
                    'timestamp_time' => '10:30',
                    'timestamp_seats' => 30
                ),
                array(
                    'timestamp_id' => 2,
                    'timestamp_time' => '16:30',
                    'timestamp_seats' => 40
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'location_id' => 2,
            'location_name' => 'Davos',
            'location_date' => '02.02.2012',
            'location_deadline' => 1323340607,
            'timestamps' => array(
                array(
                    'timestamp_id' => 3,
                    'timestamp_time' => '12:30',
                    'timestamp_seats' => 50
                ),
                array(
                    'timestamp_id' => 4,
                    'timestamp_time' => '15:30',
                    'timestamp_seats' => 60
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I hope the question is clear enough.

Greetings
Spinne

Edit:
What i did so far:

```
$event = $event_db->querySingle("SELECT * FROM rf_events WHERE event_id={$event_id}", true)

$rf_locations = $event_db->query("SELECT * FROM rf_locations WHERE event_id={$event_id}");

$locations = array();
$timestamps = array();
$counter = 0;

// Loop sql query result and save entries in $events array.
while ( $row = $rf_locations->fetchArray() ){

    $locations[$counter] = array(
        'location_id' => $row['location_id'],
        'location_name' => json_decode($row['location_name'], true),
        'location_date' => $row['location_date'],
        'location_deadline' => $row['location_deadline']
    );

    $rf_timestamps = $event_db->query("SELECT * FROM rf_timestamps WHERE location_id={$row['location_id']}");

    $counter2 = 0;

    while ( $row2 = $rf_timestamps->fetchArray() ){

        $locations[$counter]['timestamps'][$counter2] = array(
            'timestamp_id' => $row2['timestamp_id'],
            'timestamp_time' => $row2['timestamp_time'],
            'timestamp_seats' => $row2['timestamp_seats']
        );

        $counter2++;
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and you're right that JOINSs are the right way to do it. What MySQL library are you using? Do you have an example of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I am using the SQLite3 core library from PHP (http://php.net/manual/de/book.sqlite3.php). So far i did normal selects by id and created some nested while-loops and pushed the information in the array.

Comment: Please edit your post and show that code that you have so far.

Comment: Why you don't use objects for this purpose instead of array in array in array in array?

Comment: Hmm can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM rf_events, rf_locations, rf_timestamps WHERE  
rf_locations.event_id = rf_events.event_id AND 
rf_timestamps.location_id = rf_locations.event_id
```

Then, use add the data into php accordingly.

You can refer to: [MYSQL JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

Comment: Right direction but with your code i get following array extract:
`Array
(
    [event_id] => 1
    [event_name] => {"de":"Weltwirtschaftsforum","fr":"Forum \u00e9conomique mondial","it":"Forum Economico Mondiale"}
    [event_desc] => {"de":"Description DE","fr":"Description FR","it":"Description IT"}
    [event_lastedit] => 2011-12-01 10:23:35
    [location_id] => 1
    [location_name] => {"de":"Davos","fr":"Davos","it":"Davos"}
    [location_date] => 10.10.2010
    [location_deadline] => 1323340607
    [timestamp_id] => 1
    [timestamp_time] => 11:30
    [timestamp_seats] => 50
)`